# Setting PHP DateTime doesn't appear to be observing TimeZones

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm fairly new to PHP so forgive me if this is a stupid mistake that I haven't spotted

I've run into a problem where in our current system where we currently used `strtotime` and it was returning our date an hour ahead than it actually was set. E.g 1:15pm became 2:15pm when I set the timezone to be European rather than GMT.

I read that strotime had this problem but I can't get it to observe a different timezone if I try and set it.

So I tried working with PHPs `DateTime` instead.

The user enters the time and they select it as 1:15PM however we want to store it as 13:15. So I did this:

```
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $venue['startTime']);
$t_24 = $t->format('H:i:s');
```

Then I try and create my Date object

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $venue['startDay'] . ' ' . $t_24);
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo ' ' . $d->getTimestamp();
```

Trying to set the timezone after the object is set because apparently it doesn't work if you add the timezone as the third argument in `createFromFormat`

My computers time is currently observing European time currently GMT+1 because we're observing daylight savings time in the UK, I select the time set on the through our system as 1:15pm and because I've set the timezone I expect the timestamp outputted equivalent to 7:15am as it's six hours behind European time, however when I convert the timestamp `1500639300` it's still equal to 2:15 PM. Probably done something stupid but can't quite figure out what? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use gmdate() Function for this

```
<?php $current_time = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps have no time zone - they are always in UTC time. If you want to save timezone related data use another format! For example save in H:i:s, as you need it.